# Split Numeric from String

Tags: vb.net

I have String line EAUE-BCS-101.
how can separate int from above string in vb.net

i already have tried Label9.Text = Regex.Match(TextBox1.Text, "/^[A-z]+$/").Value this code but couldn't work.

Thanks

Comment: Is the numeric value always the last 3 characters?

Comment: Why don't you try some different things in a [Regex Tester](http://regexstorm.net/tester)?

Comment: Is the format always <letters>DASH<letters>DASH<digits>? If so, you could use something like `CInt(yourString.Split("-"c).Last)`

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you try with Split function? Something like this:

```
Label9.Text = stringText.Split("-")(2)
```